# get_current_screen - 'Trying to get property of non-object' error

Tags: wp-admin

Hello im using this code in the admin to filter custom post types edit.php page

but get_current_screen `$screen->post_type` is throwing a php notice.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

add_action( 'parse_query', 'filtering_edit_table' );

function filtering_edit_table( $query ) {

$screen = get_current_screen();

if( is_admin() && $screen->post_type == 'custom_post_type' && $screen->base == 'edit' ) {
           // Do some things     
            }

}
```

How can I fix this?

Edit:

I am already requiring screen.php which contains `get_current_screen()`

`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');`

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it worked fine. Where are you `require`ing `screen.php`? Same way as this?

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');
add_action( 'parse_query', 'filtering_edit_table' );

function filtering_edit_table( $query ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if( is_admin() && $screen->post_type == 'custom_post_type' && $screen->base == 'edit' ) {
        print_r($screen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working throws a Fatal error. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function current_screen()`. Also I required once the screen.php `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php');`

Comment: Testted, works fine for me. Don't require `screen.php`, it's already loaded.

Comment: I need it to work with the parse_query action hook not the current_screen action hook.

Comment: See my edit. Tested, works.

Comment: Why is this happening on my Windows computer (using WAMP) and not on my Mac (using MAMP) ?